# Android AutoCompleteTextView how can I ignore extra spaces

Tags: java, android, arrays, autocompletetextview

I have been wrestling with this issue all day. I have a simple AutoCompleteTextview and one of it's suggestions is the city of **Los Angeles** . If a user types in **Los Angeles** with 1 space in between the 2 words it works but if they type in 2 spaces or more in between the suggestions stop. This is my code

```
    AutoCompleteTextView location= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.location);
    String[] arrays= {"Los Angeles"};
// Los Angeles: this works
// Los   Angeles: this does not work notice the extra space in between
// I want to treat extra spaces as just 1 space
    location.setThreshold(2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=  new ArrayAdapter<>(Purpose.this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,arrays);
   location.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have also tried this

```
    String[] arrays= {"Los Angeles".replaceAll("  "," ")};
 // I can not obviously use trim because it merges everything
```

I have many groups of data but this is the fundamental issue, if I can fix this part then it solves the issue for the other group of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything out there that does this, personally I would just write a separate method that cleans your `String`. Something involving **[StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)**

```
for(int x = 0; x < YourString.length(); x++) {
    if(YourString[x].equals(" ") && YourString[x-1].equals(" ") {
        (StringBuilder.removeCharAt(x-1));
    }
}
```

Crude code I just typed, but just to give you some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped